# asp.net MVC Custom Filters [RESTAuthorize] is ignored

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-mvc-custom-filter

The `[RESTAuthorization]` is being ignored and instead jump into the code to Get all the Country without checking for the Rest Authorization filter.

Here is the code for `RESTAuthorization`

```
using System; 
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.Linq; 
using System.Web; 
using System.Web.Mvc; 
using MyWebsite.Repository;

namespace MyWebsite.API.Attributes
{
    public class RESTAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        private ISecurityRepository _repository;

        public RESTAuthorizeAttribute()
            : this(new SecurityRepository())
        {

        }

        public RESTAuthorizeAttribute(ISecurityRepository repository)
        {
            _repository = repository;
        }

        private const string _securityToken = "token";

        public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            if (Authorize(filterContext))
            {
                return;
            }

            HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
        }

        protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
        }

        private bool Authorize(AuthorizationContext actionContext)
        {
            try
            {
                HttpRequestBase request = actionContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request;
                string token = request.Params[_securityToken];
                string ip = _repository.GetIP(request);

                return _repository.IsTokenValid(token, ip, request.UserAgent);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the code for get all country. The `RestAuthorize` is being ignore

```
[RESTAuthorize]
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<dtoCountry> GetAllCountry()
{
    try
    {
        return _repository.GetAllCountry().ToList();
    }
    catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
    {
        throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you implement the `System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute`, you need to implement the method:

```
protected override bool IsAuthorized(HttpActionContext actionContext)
{

}
```

I believe that calling `OnAuthorization` is not necessary (but you can keep it if you need it), so your code example would look like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Controllers;

namespace MyWebsite.API.Attributes
{
    public class RESTAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        private ISecurityRepository _repository;

        public RESTAuthorizeAttribute()
            : this(new SecurityRepository())
        {

        }

        public RESTAuthorizeAttribute(ISecurityRepository repository)
        {
            _repository = repository;
        }

        private const string _securityToken = "token";

        // This function actually decides whether this request will be accepted or not
        protected override bool IsAuthorized(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            //TODO Return true or false, whether you need to accept this request or not
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: HttpRequestContext does not contain definition for HttpContext

Comment: @NiangMoore can you provide the namespaces you are using?

Comment: using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using MyWebsite.Repository;

Comment: It seems that you are implementing the `System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute` where for ASP.NET WebAPI the `System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute` is more suitable. Remove `using System.Web.Mvc;` and add `using System.Web.Http; using System.Web.Http.Controllers;` instead.

Comment: yes, I've done that but still the same HttpRequestContext does not contain definition for HttpContext

Comment: @NiangMoore, yes I see that now. I cannot find a way to address this, I guess you could use `actionContext.Request` instead. You have access to HTTP headers via `actionContext.Request.Headers`.

Comment: Cannot implicity convert type System.Net.Http.Headers.HttpRequestHeaders to System.Web.HttpRequestBase

Comment: What I meant that you need to rewrite your code a bit so that is works inside the `IsAuthorized` method. Your existing code works on System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute but for ASP.NET WebAPI it does not trigger at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public class Authorizetest: System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute
{
    private const string _securityToken = "token"; 
    public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {

       if(Authorize(actionContext))
        {
            return;
        }
        HandleUnauthorizedRequest(actionContext);  
    }

    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(HttpActionContextactionContext)
    {
        base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(actionContext);
    }

    private bool Authorize(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {         
        try
        {                           
            var context = new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current);
            HttpRequestBase request = context.Request;              
            string token = request.Params[_securityToken];
            bool xyz = ValidatingTokens.IsTokenValid(token, 
            CommonManager.GetIP(request), request.UserAgent);
            return xyz;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```