# Web api Authorization filter not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am following the tutorial [secure web api](http://www.primaryobjects.com/2015/05/08/token-based-authentication-for-web-service-apis-in-c-mvc-net/). And added this code in custom authorization attribute.But this filter is not working ,its not firing , the break points donot hit.When i use it on some action then action is called but this attribute is not called.

```
public class RESTAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    private const string _securityToken = "token";

    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (Authorize(filterContext))
        {
            return;
        }

        HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
    }

    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
    }

    private bool Authorize(AuthorizationContext actionContext)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpRequestBase request = actionContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request;
            string token = request.Params[_securityToken];

            return SecurityManager.IsTokenValid(token, CommonManager.GetIP(request), request.UserAgent);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

for action:

```
  [RESTAuthorize]               //this donot get fired,bpoint not hit
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()//this fires and bpoint hit 
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }
```

Comment: You should add the code you are using to add the attribute to the controller/action (just in case the problem is there).

Comment: try adding it globally - `config.Filters.Add(new RESTAuthorizeAttribute());` in `WebApiConfig.cs`

Comment: It looks like someone else has had a similar issue, perhaps this thread will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37371667/asp-net-mvc-custom-filters-restauthorize-is-ignored

Comment: Also there are some good resources for authorisation and authentication on the asp.net site. I would say you are mixing them together by doing both in one attribute, but here are the links: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/authentication-filters  &  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/authentication-and-authorization-in-aspnet-web-api

Comment: @AjayAradhya yes it worked but now the attribute is calling on every controller action, no matter i decorate it with attribute or not,anyother way to resolve it.

Comment: @AjayAradhya i think I have to add allowanonymous for this.

Comment: allowanonymuous is not working.

Comment: ok so assigning attribute globally works but the specific decoration won't work?

Comment: Can you make a simple attribute and check if it works with decoration? If thats the case, you have to reconsider your `RESTAuthorizeAttribute` class.

Comment: @AjayAradhya if i add attribute in webapiconfig then it is called on all actions , but the problem is that how i can exclude the actions where i dont want this attribute.In this case allowanonymous is also not working.

Comment: @AjayAradhya i have tried to add a simple attribute many times , by creating new project but same issue.